# SQL Server add padding to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have written a query to create a string and to add padding between the values. This is then exported as a text file in order to load into a legacy system.

I have used a table variable to extract all the source data from table1 then run a query using CAST to create the required string with padding.

My question is; can this been achieved using fewer steps, without using a table variable (or temp table) and is CAST the best way to do it?

Unfortunately, using a padded string is the only way to create a suitable upload file.

Sample data and query:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1(
    [source1] [varchar](6),
    [source2] [varchar](8),
    [source3] [varchar](6),
    [source4] [varchar](3),
    [source5] [varchar](10),
    [source6] [varchar](5),
    [source7] [decimal](17, 2)
    );


INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (999999,55566889,8964,'OPL',25648,'CR',12.35);
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (222222,44422258,2548,'EWP',25698,'CR',10248.25);
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (999999,33355589,3655,'SDO',75869,'DR',-897623.25);
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (444444,11155987,5742,'SVI',25698,'CR',100023.36);
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 VALUES (555555,41555585,2586,'PLW',65879,'DR',-45.69);

Declare @TempTableVariable Table(
    column1 nchar(15),
    column2 nchar(6),
    column3 nchar(3),
    column4 nchar(10),
    column5 nchar(6),
    column6 nchar(25),
    column7 nchar(17),
    column8 nchar(17)
    );

INSERT INTO @TempTableVariable
SELECT
    source1 + source2 AS column1,
    source3 AS column2,
    source4 AS column3,
    source5 AS column4,
    source1 AS column5,
    source6 AS column6,
    CASE WHEN source7 > 0 THEN ABS(source7) ELSE NULL END AS column7,
    CASE WHEN source7 < 0 THEN ABS(source7) ELSE NULL END AS column8
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE source1 = '999999';

SELECT
    column1 AS SetID,
    CAST(ISNULL(column2,'') AS nchar(4)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column3,'') AS nchar(6)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column4,'') AS nchar(14)) +
    CAST(column5 AS nchar(7)) +
    CAST(column1 AS nchar(15)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column7,'') AS nchar(17)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column8,'') AS nchar(17)) AS Input
FROM @TempTableVariable;
```

Result:

```
SETID|INPUT 
99999955566889|8964OPL   25648         999999 99999955566889 12.35            
99999933355589|3655SDO   75869         999999 99999933355589                  897623.25
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could wrap the INSERT statement in a CTE instead and get rid of the @TempTableVariable, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with a CTE would be the following:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT
    source1 + source2 AS column1,
    source3 AS column2,
    source4 AS column3,
    source5 AS column4,
    source1 AS column5,
    source6 AS column6,
    CASE WHEN source7 > 0 THEN ABS(source7) ELSE NULL END AS column7,
    CASE WHEN source7 < 0 THEN ABS(source7) ELSE NULL END AS column8
  FROM dbo.table1
  WHERE source1 = '999999'
)
SELECT
    column1 AS SetID,
    CAST(ISNULL(column2,'') AS nchar(4)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column3,'') AS nchar(6)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(column4,'') AS nchar(14)) +
    CAST(column5 AS nchar(7)) +
    CAST(column1 AS nchar(15)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(CAST(column7 AS nchar(17)),'') AS nchar(17)) +
    CAST(ISNULL(CAST(column8 AS nchar(17)),'') AS nchar(17)) AS Input
FROM cte
```

Slightly edited the post to overcome the fact that '' can't be CAST as decimal.

Comment: I've never used CTE before. Good to know. How well would this work with a large recored set... maybe 500K or so?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using the @temp table, but try this:

```
 SELECT
        CAST(source1 + source2 AS nchar(15)) as column1,
        CAST(ISNULL(source2,'') AS nchar(4))+
        CAST(ISNULL(column4,'') AS nchar(6))+
        CAST(ISNULL(column5,'') AS nchar(14))+
        CAST(column1 AS nchar(7)) +
        CAST(column6 AS nchar(15)) +
        CASE WHEN source7 > 0 THEN CAST(ISNULL(abs(source7),'') AS nchar(17))  
             ELSE NULL END +
        CASE WHEN source7 < 0 THEN CAST(ISNULL(abs(source7),'') AS nchar(17))  
             ELSE NULL END AS column2

    FROM dbo.table1
    WHERE source1 = '999999';
```

Can't test it, but should be would you need...

Comment: Hi, thanks for you input but this wont achieve the required result. Your query would give 8 result columns when it needs to be just 2, with required padding. I used a temp table to allow me to successfully deal with the NULLs as any NULLs would result in NULL on my Input column.

Comment: My apologies, it wasn't 100% clear in your post.  You can concatenate columns (replace comma in example above with + where you want to combine column)   I revised the query to concatenate the results into two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BCP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx) utility with a format file.  Instead of hand-crafting the output, you tell SQL Server the layout of your text file and then let it do all the work. It's also really fast.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="|"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="4"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="6"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="14"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="7"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="15"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="17"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm"  TERMINATOR="\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="c1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="c2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="c3" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="c4" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="c5" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="c6" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="c7" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="c8" xsi:type="SQLCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is completely alien to me but I am intrigued. I will look into this some more.